# Is the cookie dependent on the browser?

Tags: http, web, cookies, https, state-management

I'm a little confused about the cookie and I want to know can we use cookies somewhere other than the browser, like a mobile app or desktop app. Is the cookie dependent on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, cookie is not dependent on browser.

Cookie is dependent on HTTP "User-Agent" -- the software/library client that is acting on behalf of a user, following HTTP protocol. Browser is just one type of it. Other types of "User-Agent" includes:

- CLI software that can send HTTP request, such as [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).
- Library that can be imported in project and send HTTP request. Take Node.js project for example, they can be [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). All major programming language have its own HTTP client libraries.
- Self-implemented HTTP client logic code.
- more...

In a mobile app or desktop app, if HTTP is used for application, it is highly likely that cookie is used.

Answer (score 1):

Any HTTP client can use cookies. A cookie is just a HTTP header sent by the server, with a value that is sent back to the server by the client in subsequent requests. Consult the documentation of your HTTP client to see if there is built-in support for remembering cookies.

Answer (score 1):

**Session Based Authentication**

In the session based authentication, the server will create a session for the user after the user logs in. The session id is then stored on a cookie on the user’s browser. While the user stays logged in, the cookie would be sent along with every subsequent request. The server can then compare the session id stored on the cookie against the session information stored in the memory to verify user’s identity and sends response with the corresponding state!

**Token Based Authentication**

Many web applications use JSON Web Token (JWT) instead of sessions for authentication. In the token based application, the server creates JWT with a secret and sends the JWT to the client. The client stores the JWT (usually in local storage) and includes JWT in the header with every request. The server would then validate the JWT with every request from the client and sends response.

**The biggest difference** here is that the user’s state is not stored on the server, as the state is stored inside the token on the client side instead. Most of the modern web applications use JWT for authentication for reasons including scalability and mobile device authentication.

**Scalability**

**Session based authentication:** Because the sessions are stored in the server’s memory, scaling becomes an issue when there is a huge number of users using the system at once.

**Token based authentication:** There is no issue with scaling because token is stored on the client side.

**Multiple Device**

**Session based authentication:** Cookies normally work on a single domain or subdomains and they are normally disabled by browser if they work cross-domain (3rd party cookies). It poses issues when APIs are served from a different domain to mobile and web devices.

Token based authentication: There is no issue with cookies as the JWT is included in the request header.

**Token Based Authentication:** using JWT is the more recommended method in modern web apps. One drawback with JWT is that the size of JWT is much bigger comparing with the session id stored in cookie because JWT contains more user information. Care must be taken to ensure only the necessary information is included in JWT and sensitive information should be omitted to prevent XSS security attacks.